# Mongoengine: Manual Reference with ListField()

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'm currently creating a python script with mongoengine that requires me to use a list of objects.

```
class Clients(DynamicDocument):
    first_name = StringField()
    last_name = StringField()
    address = StringField()
    phone_number = StringField()
    email = StringField()
    password = StringField()
    vehicles = ListField(ReferenceField(Vehicles))
    deleted = BooleanField()
    appointments = ListField(ObjectIdField())
```

I know that making `ListField(ReferenceField())` would be in `DBRef` form with MongoDB. However, my intention was to get a manual reference so that I can get the ObjectId of the `Vehicles`. In other words, I would like the database to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSsl7.png) and not like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAhVf.png). Is there a way to do so???

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to store the references as ObjectId, instead of DBRef. MongoEngine by default stores ObjectId, not ReferenceField but this is actually customizable (see dbref arg on [ReferenceField](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField))

```
ListField(ReferenceField(Vehicles, dbref=False)) # will store [ObjectId] (the default)
```

vs

```
ListField(ReferenceField(Vehicles, dbref=True)) # will store [DBRef]
```